# Use GitHub to change visibility of ghcr.io package

Tags: github-api

I have published a number of Docker images to ghcr.io. They are all private. I want to make them public. I do not want to do this by hand because 1) there are 100+ and 2) As I add more images I want them to be made public as part of the deployment workflow.

The only reference I can find is [this](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/55094) thread on the GitHub community, but the example does not work for me (same issue as the OP).

Currently the repo belongs to me, but ultimately I will move it under an organisation assuming I'm able to make the packages public there too.

Querying a package:

```json
$ curl -H "Authorization: token <REDACTED>" \
>   https://api.github.com/users/mkst/packages/container/compilers%2Fmacosx%2Fgcc-5026
{
  "id": 5587222,
  "name": "compilers/macosx/gcc-5026",
  "package_type": "container",
  "owner": {
    "login": "mkst",
    "id": 22226349,
    "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjIyMjI2MzQ5",
    "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/22226349?v=4",
    "gravatar_id": "",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/users/mkst",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/mkst",
    "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mkst/followers",
    "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mkst/following{/other_user}",
    "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mkst/gists{/gist_id}",
    "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mkst/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
    "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mkst/subscriptions",
    "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mkst/orgs",
    "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mkst/repos",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mkst/events{/privacy}",
    "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mkst/received_events",
    "type": "User",
    "site_admin": false
  },
  "version_count": 8,
  "visibility": "private",
  "url": "https://api.github.com/users/mkst/packages/container/compilers%2Fmacosx%2Fgcc-5026",
  "created_at": "2023-09-10T16:38:20Z",
  "updated_at": "2023-09-11T20:47:23Z",
  "html_url": "https://github.com/users/mkst/packages/container/package/compilers%2Fmacosx%2Fgcc-5026"
}
```

Then:

```json
$ curl -X PATCH \
>   -H "Authorization: token <REDACTED>" \
>   -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.package-deletes-preview+json" \
>   -d '{"visibility":"public"}' \
>   https://api.github.com/users/mkst/packages/container/compilers%2Fmacosx%2Fgcc-5026
{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest"
}
```

I'm happy to use graphql if I can change the visibility using that instead, but right now I'm stuck and at this point I could have spent the time struggling with the API just  changing visibility manually!

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is:

It's not possible to use this API to change the visibility of ORGANISATION packages.

The longer answer is:

The images were published using my own GitHub PAT, rather than using the implicit `${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}` within the GitHub Action. This meant that they belonged to the `mkst` organisation instead of belonging to the `mkst/compilers` repository.

For anyone else stumbling across this, you will need to delete the packages and then redeploy. Here's a snippet of the action yaml for reference:

```yaml
  deploy:
    name: deploy the stuff
    permissions: write-all # important!
    ...
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Log in to GitHub Container Registry
        uses: docker/login-action@v3
        with:
          registry: ghcr.io
          username: ${{ github.repository_owner }}
          password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} # important!

      - name: Build and push to Github registry
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v4
        with:
          push: true
          tags: ghcr.io/{{ github.repo }}/${{ matrix.image }}:latest
          file: ${{ matrix.dockerfile }}
```

Comment: How did you make them public?  I'm currently trying to do this outside of GitHub with either CLI or API (curl), not the web page.

Comment: I deleted the packages (via API I think?) and re-published them using the "correct" token, such that the packages were owned by my _repository_ (i.e. `mkst/compilers`) rather than an organisation named `mkst`